# How to create sql syntax autocomplete using angular

Tags: angular, postgresql, autocomplete

I am trying to create a sql editor for Postegresql Database( create queries, executing queries, etc) using Anguar. I have been a while searching for tool to autocomplete sql syntax. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Code Mirror https://codemirror.net/mode/sql/index.html or Monaco editor should do the job

Comment: Thank you, I've worked with codeMirror. It works as a charm!